# How to Let Float Items Split the Blank Area in Average?

Tags: javascript, html, css, grid, css-float

Please run this demo:

```css
.app {
  background:pink;
  width: 90vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.app__item {
  background: lightblue;
  width: 200px;
  float :left;
  margin:5px;
  height: 40px;
}
.app__item:last-child {
  float: right;
}
.app__item--size2 {
  height: 90px;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <div class="app__item app__item--size2">1</div>
  <div class="app__item">2</div>
  <div class="app__item">3</div>
  <div class="app__item">4</div>
  <div class="app__item">5</div>
  <div class="app__item">6</div>
  <div class="app__item">7</div>
  <div class="app__item">8</div>
  <div class="app__item">9</div>
  <div class="app__item">10</div>
  <div class="app__item">
    <button>search</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please notice the red color text which is what I want:

[image]

**How to Let Float Items Split the Blank Area in Average?**

This gif point out what I want and also the reason why I am using float layout.

[image]

If using flex, the result would be

```css
.app {
  background:pink;
  width: 80vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.app__item,
.app__item_wrapper {
    margin:5px;    
  width: 200px;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
.app__item {
  background: lightblue;
  height: 40px;
}
.app__item_wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.app__item--size2 {
  height: 90px;
}
.app__item--inner {
  margin:0;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <div class="app__item app__item--size2">1</div>
  <div class=" app__item_wrapper app__item--size2">
    <div class="app__item app__item--inner">2</div>
    <div class="app__item app__item--inner">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class=" app__item_wrapper app__item--size2">
    <div class="app__item app__item--inner">4</div>
    <div class="app__item app__item--inner">5</div>
  </div>

  <div class="app__item">6</div>
  <div class="app__item">7</div>
  <div class="app__item">8</div>
  <div class="app__item">
    <button>search</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the con is that it won't work well when viewport is changing. See this:

[image]

and this is the con:

[image]

Comment: why downvoted? Please tell me So I can improve the question.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you're wanting the cells to the right of "cell 1" to stretch-to-fill the reaming horizontal space of the enclosing div (with pink background).

You could use [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid) to achieve this as shown below:

```css
.app {
  background:pink;
  width: 90vw;
  padding:5px;
  
  display:grid;
  
  /* Cause first column with to be 200px, remaining two columns
  to scale to fit remaining width */
  grid-template-columns: 200px repeat(2, 1fr);
  
  /* Set spacing between cells */
  grid-gap:10px;
}
.app__item {
  
  background: lightblue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
} 
.app__item--size2 {
  /* Cause top left cell to occupy two rows */
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <div class="app__item app__item--size2">1</div>
  <div class="app__item">2</div>
  <div class="app__item">3</div>
  <div class="app__item">4</div>
  <div class="app__item">5</div>
  <div class="app__item">6</div>
  <div class="app__item">7</div>
  <div class="app__item">8</div>
  <div class="app__item">9</div>
  <div class="app__item">10</div>
  <div class="app__item">
    <button>search</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank @Dacre Denny for giving me inspiration. Finally, I got it.

```css
.app {
  background:pink;
  width: 90vw;
  padding:5px;
  
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit,200px);
  justify-content:space-evenly;
  grid-gap: 5px;
}
.app__item {  
  background: lightblue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
} 
.app__item--size2 {
  /* Cause top left cell to occupy two rows */
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
  height:100%;
}
.app__item:last-child {
  grid-column-end: -1
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <div class="app__item app__item--size2">1</div>
  <div class="app__item">2</div>
  <div class="app__item">3</div>
  <div class="app__item">4</div>
  <div class="app__item">5</div>
  <div class="app__item">6</div>
  <div class="app__item">7</div>
  <div class="app__item">8</div>
  <div class="app__item">9</div>
  <div class="app__item">10</div>
  <div class="app__item">
    <button>search</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

See this gif when viewport is changing.

[image]